# CSV file now showing up in tabular format upon using read_csv command in Notebook on R

Tags: r, dataframe, kaggle

```
library(tidyverse) # metapackage of all tidyverse packages

# Input data files are available in the read-only "../input/" directory" directory
# For example, running this (by clicking run or pressing Shift+Enter) will list all files under the input directory

list.files(path = "../input/students-dropout-and-academic-success-dataset")

students = read_csv("/kaggle/input/students-dropout-and-academic-success-dataset/data.csv")

spec(students)

students
```

Giving me the output like this instead of a tabular format :(
[image]

Tried everything but nothing works

Answer (score 1):

It seems the separator is a semicolon (;). You can read that format using `read_csv2()`.